# Crash on java.lang.AbstractMethodError android.text.TextUtils.writeToParcel may be related to accessability

Tags: java, android, crash

I am seeing following crashes on my Google Play Console for my Android App. I am not able to reproduce these issues nor I know where in App this crashes are happening? (it is happening for devices running 6.0 or higher)

Crash 1

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
  at android.text.TextUtils.writeToParcel (TextUtils.java:648)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeCharSequence (Parcel.java:585)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue (Parcel.java:1420)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeList (Parcel.java:811)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.writeAccessibilityRecordToParcel (AccessibilityEvent.java:1174)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.writeToParcel (AccessibilityEvent.java:1140)
  at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub$Proxy.sendAccessibilityEvent (IAccessibilityManager.java:269)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityManager.java:319)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6725)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent (ViewGroup.java:891)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal (View.java:6298)
  at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (View.java:23345)
  at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:248)
  at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateApi16Impl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:148)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (View.java:6275)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked (RecyclerView.java:3304)
  at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal (View.java:6254)
  at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent (View.java:23303)
  at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:226)
  at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateApi16Impl$1.sendAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:143)
```

Crash 2

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
  at android.text.TextUtils.writeToParcel (TextUtils.java:654)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeCharSequence (Parcel.java:586)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.writeToParcel (AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2795)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList (Parcel.java:1222)
  at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityInteractionConnectionCallback$Stub$Proxy.setFindAccessibilityNodeInfosResult (IAccessibilityInteractionConnectionCallback.java:140)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:168)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap1 (AccessibilityInteractionController.java)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1198)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6343)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had created custom spans for my texts which implemented "ParcelableSpan" which was creating these errors

my original implementation was

```
public class NativeArticleBulletSpan  implements LeadingMarginSpan, ParcelableSpan
```

after looking at the documentation for ParcelableSpan on
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ParcelableSpan.html 
which says "This can only be used by code in the framework; it is not intended for applications to implement their own Parcelable spans."

I have changed my custom span implementations to following to fix the error

```
public class NativeArticleBulletSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan
```